# Time to remove WAL from Postrgres

Tags: postgresql, wal

Just curious as to why it takes so long to remove WAL from a table in Postgres

```
ALTER TABLE tablename SET UNLOGGED
```

Took more than an hour on a very large table but with very little CPU utilization.
Is it removal of files on disk?
Presumably it takes a long time to reinstate the WAL.

As I say, just curious.

Thanks.

Comment: It was probably waiting to get the exclusive lock on the table.

Comment: WAL is not contained in tables.  Removing the WAL from a table doesn't make any sense.  Are you asking about how long it takes the command to run?  How long it takes for the steady-state size of pg_wal to shrink?  something else?

Comment: I had a large amount of data to import into an already large table. I had read that (among disabling triggers, indexes etc) there may be an increase in import performance on disabling WAL on the table taking the data. As an experiment I used the command above and was surprised at the length of time required to execute. as @a_horse_with_no_name suggested I suspected a wait for exclusive lock, even though I was the only user.

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Improve_the_performance_of_ALTER_TABLE_SET_LOGGED_UNLOGGED_statement

"However this design lead us to performance problems with large relations because we need to rewrite the entire content of the relation twice, one into a new heap and other into the WAL, so this project will change the current desing of the mechanism of change an unlogged table to logged without the need to rewrite the entire heap, but just by removing the init forks and if the wal_level != minimal we'll write the contents to the WAL too."